# How can i click button and add or minus value by using function (Svelte)

Tags: svelte

I am newbie with Svelte. I have written functions for increasing and decreasing value in the textbox when clicking + and - button. But I try to click + and - buttons but it is not response anything. plz help me.
This code below:

```
<script>
    var name;
    var count = {
        cetiya : 0,
        other : 0
    };
    function addNumPray(name) {
        console.log(name);
        if (name == "a") {
            count.cetiya += 1;
        } else {
            count.other += 1;
        }
    }

    function minusNumPray(name) {
        console.log(name);
        if (name == "a") {
            count.cetiya -= 1;
        } else {
            count.other -= 1;
        }
    }
</script>



<div>
    <button on:click={minusNumPray("a")}>-</button>
  <input type="text" name="numPrayAtCetiya" size="7" bind:value={count.cetiya}>
  <button on:click={addNumPray("a")}>+</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button on:click={minusNumPray("b")}>-</button>
  <input type="text" name="numPrayAtOther" size="7" bind:value={count.other}>
  <button on:click={addNumPray("b")}>+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *on:click* you have to write a function, currently you have function call instead, that will be fired on render and it's result stored in the click event. To fire a function the correct way would be:

`<button on:click={() => addNumPrary("b")}>+</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions to call functions with paramter

```
<script>
    var name;
    var count = {
        cetiya : 0,
        other : 0
    };
    function addNumPray(name) {
        console.log(name);
        if (name == "a") {
            count.cetiya += 1;
        } else {
            count.other += 1;
        }
    }

    function minusNumPray(name) {
        console.log(name);
        if (name == "a") {
            count.cetiya -= 1;
        } else {
            count.other -= 1;
        }
    }
</script>



<div>
    <button on:click={() => minusNumPray("a")}>-</button>
  <input type="text" name="numPrayAtCetiya" size="7" bind:value={count.cetiya}>
  <button on:click={() => addNumPray("a")}>+</button>
</div>
<div>
    <button on:click={() => minusNumPray("b")}>-</button>
  <input type="text" name="numPrayAtOther" size="7" bind:value={count.other}>
  <button on:click={() => addNumPray("b")}>+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for

```
<button on:click="{increaseNum}">➕</button>
<button on:click="{decreaseNum}">➖</button>
<input value="{count}" size="5"/>

<script>
  let count = 0
  let increaseNum = () => count += 1    
  let decreaseNum = () => count -= 1    
</script>
```

[image]

Another way

```
<button on:click={() => count += 1}>➕</button>
<button on:click={() => count -= 1}>➖</button>
<input value={count} size='5'/>

<script> let count = 0 </script>
```